# Removing Javascript alert line stops my append code working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, alert

So, I've got the below code: -

```
function testing(results) {
    $table = $('#formList')

    for (var event in results) {
        var formIDX = results[event]["forms_idx"]
        var formID = results[event]["form_id"]
        var eventIDX = results[event]["events_idx"]
        var eventID = results[event]["event_id"]
        var objID = results[event]["object_id"]
        var testVal = results[event]["value"]

alert($table.find("#" + formIDX).find('td:eq(1)').find("div").find("table").html())

        $subTable = $table.find("#" + formIDX).find('td:eq(1)').find("div").find("table")

        var url ="http://localhost:3278/FARTFramework/testScenario/ajaxPopulateSubTables" 

        $.post(url, {
            formID: formID, eventIDX:eventIDX, eventID:eventID, objID:objID, testVal:testVal
        }, function(data) {
            $subTable.append(data);
        }).done(function(){});
    }
}
```

It basically takes a JSON file and then adds the data into the right sub tables within a main table via appends etc.

The oddity is during debug I had an alert in there to check the html of the table it was identifying (making sure it had found the right sub table etc) and all worked well.  But if I remove that alert it then suddenly only appends all the data to the last sub table in the main table?!  Any clues?

Comment: That's how asynchronous stuff works, the loop continues and completes, and ***then*** the content is inserted with ajax, the alert just halts the operation long enough for the ajax to complete. In other words, your logic is flawed, you have to wait for the ajax call to complete before you go on to the next iteration (and please don't just set it to async:false) !

Comment: thanks for the explanation @adeneo, any suggestions as to how to make this happen?  I'm afraid my google-fu has abandoned me and I'm new to ajax (well most of it really!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a classic JavaScript closure-loop problem. The variables defined in the `for` loop are being reassigned each time within the loop and responses from the AJAX requests(which are async) get appended to the last sub-table. It works when you have an alert because the variables have not been reassigned(as alert blocks the for loop execution) by the time AJAX request is completed.

You could handle this by having a function do the AJAX request and append. The variables are not reassigned within this function and hence should work.

```
    function testing(results) {
    $table = $('#formList')

    function appendSubTable(formIDX, formID, eventIDX, eventID, objID, testVal){
        alert($table.find("#" + formIDX).find('td:eq(1)').find("div").find("table").html())

        var $subTable = $table.find("#" + formIDX).find('td:eq(1)').find("div").find("table")

        var url ="http://localhost:3278/FARTFramework/testScenario/ajaxPopulateSubTables" 

        $.post(url, {
            formID: formID, eventIDX:eventIDX, eventID:eventID, objID:objID, testVal:testVal
        }, function(data) {
            $subTable.append(data);
        }).done(function(){});
    }

    for (var event in results) {
        var formIDX = results[event]["forms_idx"]
        var formID = results[event]["form_id"]
        var eventIDX = results[event]["events_idx"]
        var eventID = results[event]["event_id"]
        var objID = results[event]["object_id"]
        var testVal = results[event]["value"]

        appendSubTable(formIDX, formID, eventIDX, eventID, objID, testVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Appears to do the tricky nicely, cheers!  Oddly the first time I tried it on the final table of the three it had swapped the two entries around, so for example if objects 5 and 6 should have been in the final table it was putting 6 before 5, but after that first time it seems to work fine!  I'll keep an eye on it but otherwise looks good!  Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code, I can't say for sure.  But when I had a similar issue it was because I was using append outside of my `$(document).ready(function(){ /*stuff here*/ })`

Essentially the object I was appending to hadn't loaded yet.

Comment: Sadly in this case I'm doing things right, to start with at least, in that my function is called from within a $(document).ready() thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
$subTable = $table.find("#" + formIDX).find('td:eq(1)').find("div").find("table")
```

To your callback function:

```
$.post(url, {
    formID: formID, eventIDX:eventIDX, eventID:eventID, objID:objID, testVal:testVal
}, function(data) {
    $subTable = $table.find("#" + formIDX).find('td:eq(1)').find("div").find("table")
    $subTable.append(data);
}).done(function(){});
```

Comment: And I just realised why. Although this code prevents `$subtable` from moving on, `formIDX` is still changing.

Comment: Dammit vsr got there first!

Answer (score 0):

in your Ajax call use its argument 'async';
  it accepts Boolean value, pass the value 'false' in it.

Try it

Comment: He doesn't want it to be synchronous, surely?